# Lens and plane mirror: inverted or not?

Tags: optics, reflection, geometric-optics, lenses

[image]

In a situation like this, I understood that the focal length is half of that of the original lens. However, I don't know whether its image is inverted or not. In this situation, will the image be inverted?

Comment: Check it yourself, you only have to take a point above O. Of course you cannot tell if an image is inverted if it is only one point, a point is self.-symmetric. You need two points to know if it is inverted or not

Answer (score 0):

The image will be inverted. You can think this combination as concave mirror. The beam reflected from the mirror will be converging spherical wave same as concave mirror (ideally).